# Transportation theory algorithms detail description

Tags: algorithms, operations-research

I'm currently study operations research and want to implement some of its algorithms programmatically. I'm now interested in these algorithms:
1.North west corner rule method in transportation theory.

1. Potentials Method for finding optimal solution in transportation theory.
2. Duality
3. Table Simplex method

I can't find any information about this method which will help me to
    implement this programmatically (by which I mean: detailed steps and algorithm
    description).

Maybe someone give useful links or describe this
    method in a form ready for program implementation (detailed steps and instructions)?

Comment: Don't you think this is more apt for the theoretical computer sciences forum(http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

in fact any of those methods, except Duality, can be read as an algorithm since it is made of some steps. You can easily find those methods in any operation research book. The important thing about program those methods is to understand clearly what each step does, and you will programme it according to your background in programming. I recently programed an PRIM algorithm and an simplex algorithm in VB. email me if you want so we can exchange soma ideas. r_almeida80@hotmail.com
Best regards.